# Get a log message from scrapy spider and assign it to a variable

Tags: python, logging, scrapy

I want to check the log message from this logger: [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] and based on it the function will do a specific action so basically I want to assign the message to a variable as a string and then find a keyword in that string

In the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html) I didn't find a way to do that it's all about formatting the logs

```
import scrapy

class spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider1'
    allowed_domains = []
    custom_settings = {'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 2}
    start_urls = ['https://quotes.toscrape.com/']


    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.text)
```

Log example

```
2022-02-03 03:11:42 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <402 https://quotes.toscrape.com/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

I want to assign the above log message to a variable

I know I can output the whole log to a .txt file but as I'll have multiple spiders run in an infinit loop there will be a huge amount of data to iterate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a logging filter and apply it to the specific `scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror` logger. You can then use regex to capture the exact type of error you would like to filter for and then write it to a file. See below sample code:

```py
import scrapy
import logging
import re

class ContentFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        match = re.search(r'Ignoring response <.*> HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed', record.msg)
        if match:
            with open("logged_messages.log", "a") as f:
                f.write(record.msg + '\n')
            return True

class spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider1'
    allowed_domains = []
    custom_settings = {'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 2}
    start_urls = ['https://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logger = logging.getLogger('scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror')
        logger.addFilter(ContentFilter())

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            "title": response.css("title::text").get()
        }
```

Read more about the logging module and the customization you can do from the [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html)